# Email notifications - Set as per the user

Tags: sharepoint-email

Need your help in solving below sharepoint issue i am facing.
I have a list added and have given access to almost 200 people.
Now issue is if i set alert me option, and set it for every one.
Anything added/modified throws an email.

How can i set the notification based on if any new item is added to the list, email should go only to particular set of people. Please help
I do not have sharepoint designer with me and neither i can get it from company.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in your workflow setting and can uncheck the option of triggering the workflow when an item is edited/modified. Make sure only check box which has an option of running workflow when an item is added is checked rest all are unchecked. Doing so will run your workflow only when an item is added, not in the case of when items are modified and hence users will receive emails only when new item is created. To send emails to a particular group of people you can create a sharepoint group an can add those people to whom you want to send the emails. Then in send email action configure that group

Comment: I think this post relates to "Alert me" function, not workflow

Answer (score 0):

Click the Alert Me button on the list, then Manage My Alerts.  Select your alert. Change the settings for Change Type to "New items are added".

You may be able to use an OOTB workflow for this, but those are primarily optimized for approvals and retention, instead of just notification.  The Three-State workflow might be helpful.  That can be found under List Settings, then Workflow Settings and Add a workflow.